# Calculating the days left between two epoch time values JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If I am given an end date in epoch time, how do I use the current time to calculate the days left before the end epoch time given?

Epoch time given example:

```
1444958355000
```

Getting current day in epoch:

```
var day = new Date();
var time = day.getTime();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938) and [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Divide by 1000 to get seconds, then by 60 for minutes, then by 60 for hours, then by 24 for days:

```
var timeleft = 1444958355000 - (new Date()).getTime();
var days = Math.ceil((((timeleft / 1000) / 60) / 60) / 24)
//days = 60;
```

Comment: OMG, this was the best solution that I saw till now. Solved my long running issue in 2 mins.
Thanks :)